# Marking a function as inline when compiling with -O3?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, inline

C++ allows you to annotate functions with the `inline` keyword. From what I understand, this provides a hint (but no obligation) to the compiler to inline the function, thereby avoiding the small function calling overhead.

I have some methods which are called so often that they really should be inlined. But `inline`-annotated functions need to be implemented in the header, so this makes the code less well-arranged. Also, I think that inlining is a compiler optimization that should happen transparently to the programmer where it makes sense.

So, do I have to annotate my functions with `inline` for inlining to happen, or does GCC figure this out without the annotation when I compile with `-O3` or other appropriate optimization flags?

Comment: "*inline-annotated functions need to be implemented in the header*" - This is not a true statement.

Comment: Link-time optimisation can inline functions not in the header. `inline`'s primary meaning is that of "this *can* be in the header", but not *must*.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Inline.html in particular, note that (1) gcc only inlines when optimizing (with -O flag) or use *__attribute__((always_inline))* (2) sometimes it can't inline because of technical reasons (use -Winline to get a warning when this happens) (3) gcc may decide to inline functions that are not marked as inline (turn this off with -fno-default-inline).  basically, when you use the -O flag, it will inline all the inline functions unless it is not possible to do so.  it may inline other functions that aren't marked as inline.

Comment: @thang: Quoting from GCC 3.4.3 is quoting 'ancient scripture'.  You might refer to [GCC 4.7.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Inline.html) instead, perhaps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good call.  i need to update my system :p  although it seems things haven't changed much with respect to inline.

Comment: Re: "thereby avoiding the small function calling overhead" - **and** potentially enabling better optimization, because the code in the body of an inlined function will go into the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inline` being just a suggestion to compiler is not true & is misleading.There are two possible effects of marking a function inline:

1. Substitution of function definition inline to where the function call was made &
2. Certain relaxations w.r.t [One definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), allowing you to define functions in header files.

An compiler may or may not perform `#1` but it has to abide to `#2`. So inline is not just a suggestion.There are some rules which will be applied once function is marked inline.

As a general guideline, do not mark your functions `inline` just for sake of optimizations. Most modern compilers will perform these optimizations on their own without your help. Mark your functions `inline` if you wish to include them in header files because it is the only correct way to include a function definition in header file without breaking the ODR.

Answer (score 1):

Common folklore is that gcc always decides on its own (based on some cost heuristics) whether to inline something or not (depending on the compiler/linker options, it can even do so at link time). You can observe this sometimes when using -Winline where gcc warns that an inline hint was ignored, it often even gives a reason.

If you want to know exactly what is going on, you probably have to read the source code of it, or take the word of someone who read it.